# Objective-C: What's the difference between NULL, nil and @""?

Tags: objective-c, null

As the title says, what's the difference between `NULL`, `nil` and `@""` ?

For example, if I want to check a string in a dictionary is empty.

Which condition should I use ?

```
if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"aString"] == nil)
```

or

```
if [[dictionary objectForKey:@"aString"] isEqualToString:@""]
```

or

```
if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"aString"] == NULL)
```

Which one is right ?

Comment: valueForKey: is for key value coding.  You should use objectForKey: to get stuff from a dictionary.  Although it does almost the same thing, it's marginally quicker and it works correctly for keys that start with an @ sign.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`nil` is NULL's analog for objective-c objects. Actually they're the same:

```
 //MacTypes.h
 #define nil NULL
```

So

```
if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"]==nil)
if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"]==NULL)
```

both check if the specific key is present in a dictionary, although 1st line is more correct as it checks objective-c types.

About:

```
if ([[dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"] isEqualToString:@""])
```

This line checks if there's an entry in dictionary with "aString" key and compares that entry with empty string. The result will be one of the following:

- is false if there's no such entry for your key
- is true if there's entry for your key and that entry is empty string
- may crash if object for your key exists and does not respond to `-isEqualToString:` message

So depending on your needs you must use 1st line, or if you need to combine both checking if entry exists and it is not an empty string then you need 2 conditions:

```
if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"]==nil ||
               [[dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"] isEqualToString:@""])
```

Answer (score 19):

```
nil == (id) 0
Nil == (Class) 0
NULL == (void *) 0
```

@"" is an empty NSString constant.

Answer (score 16):

**nil** is used to represent a null pointer to an Objective-C object.
**Nil** is used to represent a null pointer to an Objective-C class.
**NULL** is used to represent a null pointer to anything else.

All these, happen to have the numeric value of 0. They're all zero, but "NULL" is a void *, "nil" is an id, and "Nil" is a Class pointer.

**@""** is used to denote an empty string, or say a string whose length is ZERO.

Answer (score 5):

`valueForKey:` (and most other Cocoa methods) returns a pointer (memory address) to an object. When you use the `==` symbol you're simply test the numeric value of that pointer and not the actual value of the string. When you use `isEqualToString:`, you are testing the value.

These two:

```
if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"]==nil)
if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"]==NULL)
```

are more-or-less equivalent and both test "Was the address returned equal to zero?", which is how `valueForKey:` indicates there was no object found for that key. If the dictionary does contain *any* object for that key, regardless of its value (e.g. Even an empty string) this if statement returns false.

(You normally use the `nil` version in Objective-C, as a styling convention as much as anything else)

This:

```
if ([[dictionary valueForKey:@"aString"] isEqualToString:@""])
```

Tests the actual value of the string to see if it's a zero length string. If there is no object in the dictionary, it will return false, since when you call `isEqualToString:` (or almost any other method) against a `nil` pointer you always get zero, or false.

Answer (score 1):

"The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary)." You can use nil about anywhere you can use null. The main difference is that you can send messages to nil, so you can use it in some places where null cant work. In general, just use nil. that's exactly what's happening, the programmer is choosing to put a null object into the controllers array, where nil is not allowed as a value.

It is more a contextual reference where NULL is a pointer to 0x0, nil is a non-existent objective-c object and Nil is a non-existent objective-c class, but technically they are all just 0. Also, it is NULL not null -- null is in Java or C# but not in Objective-C

or ease  ways u say

They're all zero, but "NULL" is a void *, "nil" is an id, and "Nil" is a Class pointer.

Answer (score 0):

**Nil** and **NULL** indicate the non-existence 
**@""** indicates the existence and it's empty