# NSURLCredential Authentication with only one key

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

I have an iOS app which logs-in a user and then authenticates that user with an `appKey`. The `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method on `NSURLConnection` is sufficient for providing a username / password with an `NSURLCredential`. However, I'm having trouble creating an `NSURLCredential` with only an `appKey` (just one piece of auth data, not two). Is there anyway to provide authentication details to a server with `NSURLConnection` with only a key?

The following `curl` request works perfectly by only providing the `appKey`, no password:

```
curl -u <app key>: -H "Accept: application/json" https://dev.sitename.com/api/v1/webpage -v
```

This is how I've translated the above `cURL` authentication part to Objective-C:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    // Authenticate the user with AppKey based on the credentials provided
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[keychainItem objectForKey:@"APP KEY"] password:nil persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

This should work, but every time I try it the authentication fails. As you can see I've set the `password` parameter to `nil`. I've also tried filling in both parameters. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how I could only pass one parameter to the server using `NSURLConnection`? Is there any way to get error information from the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method (I'm aware of `didReceiveResponse`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an undocumented behavior of `NSURLCredential`: when passing `nil` as a password to `credentialWithUser:password:persistence:`, and using this credential to respond the authentication challenge, iOS ignore the credential altogether.

The solution is to replace the `nil` by an empty `NSString` (`@""`) when you don't want to use a password.

So your code should look something like:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[keychainItem objectForKey:@"APP KEY"] password:@"" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
```

---

This is what I get from my nginx's logs with a `nil` password:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Aug/2013:23:21:14 +0200] "GET /tmp HTTP/1.1" 401 188 "-" "test/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0"
```

And with an empty string (`apikey` being the username used in response to the challenge):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - apikey [18/Aug/2013:23:21:16 +0200] "GET /tmp HTTP/1.1" 200 136 "-" "test/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0"
```

Comment: While reading your question again I saw the "I've also tried filling in both parameters. Nothing seems to work" bit. Did you already try the `@""` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that, but it didn't work. Also, I believe that `@""` is equivalent to `nil`.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. And no, [`nil` is not the same as `@""`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283690/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-null-nil-and). Have you tried logging the HTTP response sent by your app (with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or something similar) to see whether its a client or server problem ?

Comment: Thanks for the info - thats good to know. And it's a good thing you provided that link because the KeychainItem was being retrieved from an `NSDictionary`, and `NSURLCredential` was having some issues getting the object from the dictionary. In combination with your `@""` trick, this worked!