# What is difference between nil and Nil and Null in ios when these should be used?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, null

Where should I use nil and where should the others Null Nil
now i want to assign nil val to a string 
 nsstring=nil;

Answer (score 1):

For get different of `nil` and `null` please refer [Objective-C: What's the difference between NULL, nil and @""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283690/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-null-nil-and)

If you want to assign `nil` or `null` to `NSString` you should write

```
NSString *myStr = @""; // it empty/nil/null
```

And you can check your string is empty or not by

```
if([myStr length] == 0) // or if([myStr isEqual:[NSNull class]])
{
  // empty string;
}
else
{
  // not empty string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nil is used to represent a null pointer in objective-c as an object. Nil is to represent a null pointer for a class.
NULL is actually the same as nil. It's defined in MacTypes.h as

```
// MacTypes.h
#define nil NULL
```

You should also mention NSNull which can be used to represent a null value within NSArray, NSDictionary etc.

Comment: Well thanks alot.if we have to assign a null value to an object at some index in array then we should use NSNull.

Answer (score 0):

All three of these values represent null, or zero pointer, values. The difference is that while NULL represents zero for any pointer, nil is specific to objects (e.g., id) and Nil is specific to class pointers. It should be considered a best practice of sorts to use the right null object in the right circumstance for documentation purposes, even though there is nothing stopping someone from mixing and matching as they go along.

Refer this [Difference between nil, Nil, NULL](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2009/01/nil-vs-nil-vs-null-the-uses-and-abuses-of-null-objects/)