# Can't Set Protocol's Synthesized Property Boolean

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean, protocols, synthesize

I have a class `SSENoteTrack` that conforms to two protocols, `SSETrack` and `SSENoteContainer`. Both of those protocols declare an @property in the interface file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isMuted) BOOL muted;
```

In `SSENoteTrack.h`, I synthesize the property.

```
@synthesize muted;
```

On an instance of `SSENoteTrack`, the property starts as nil. I try to set it in another class' code like so:

```
[track setMuted:YES]
```

I can set the property to YES just fine. However, I can't set the property to NO. e.g. After the line `[track setMuted:NO]`, `track.isMuted` returns `nil`.

Quite a strange issue. Perhaps it's because of the way my protocol is set up? Thanks!

Comment: I think nil and No are the same thing, ie. zero

Comment: Isn't that what you want, for `track.isMuted` to return false, i.e. `nil` or `NO`?

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot. See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4289697/1539826
I was typing po in lldb to check isMuted, rather than p and that's why I was getting `nil` not 0.

Comment: @rizzes, put your comment as an answer, so you can marked your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I'm an idiot. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289697/1539826. I was typing `po` in lldb to check `isMuted`, rather than `p` and that's why I was getting nil not 0.